# Show that $U_{A}$ is subspace of $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I am trying to show that $U_{A}$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$.

Let $A\in$ $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ and $U_{A} = \{B  \in\Bbb R^{n\times n} :BA = AB\}$.

So for $U_{A}$ to be a subspace of $R^{n\times n}$ we need to check that it's closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication? Is it right that for $U_{A}$ to be a subspace of $R^{n\times n}$ I have to show the following conditions?

1. So I need to show that the zero vector is in  $U_{A}$.
2. $U_{A}$ is closed under addition and multiplication by a scalar in

How do I do that? I'd assume that the zero vector is indeed in $U_{A}$ since $A$ and $B$ can just be zero matrices. But scalar multiplication? Do I have to show that $\lambda BA = \lambda AB$?

I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix $A$ is 'fixed' so you cannot certainly let $A$ to be the zero matrix. (Unless of course, $A$ is already taken to be the zero matrix and in which this case the question is trivial.)

Suppose $A$ is not zero. Then $U_A$ is the collection of all $n$ matrix commuting with $A$. Suppose $B,C\in U_A$. Then note that $$A(B+C) = AB + AC = BA + CA = (B+C)A$$  where the middle equality follows from the fact  that $B$ and $C$ lie in $U_A$. So $B+C\in U_A$. This shows that it is closed under vector addition. I'll leave the rest to you.